# How to run multiple Karma & Jasmine projects in a single solution (Need for Jenkins integration)?

Tags: javascript, angular, jenkins, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

We have a large solution containing different projects of Karma & Jasmine Tests.
We are using Jenkins for CI, we want to run Karma execute command only once. Meaning: We don't want to register path of every project one by one.
Is there any way to run all the test cases by single command?

---

**What I am thinking is:**
Creating a MainTests project and referencing all the js/spec files from files[] array of other projects's karma.conf.js files inside karma.conf.js file of MainTests project and then I will run only MainTests project using Jenkins.

See screenshot below

---

Also its plain JS we are not using Angular/AngularJS

Kindly suggest an appropriate solutions, I will be thankful!

[image]

Comment: Hi @Arun. Are you using some jenkins plugin or just cmd commands? Your jenkins is on windows or linux?

Comment: Hi @JRichardsz , Thanks for your response! Yes, I am using Jenkins plugin(Node Plugin). Jenkins is on windows.

Comment: is this your plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin ??

Comment: Is just for development purposes? I mean, Jenkins and nodejs are running in your laptop or cpu?

Comment: For now it is on my local host, later I will deploy it on remote somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For now**

I have created Windows batch command to find all the karma solutions and run NPM Install
And karma start

Its working for me.

See the batch command below:

```
@Echo off

Echo Searching for new karma.conf.js files...

FOR /R "%WORKSPACE%" %%F IN (.) DO (

ECHO Node module found!

    Echo inside %%F 

IF EXIST "%%F\karma.conf.js" (

   ECHO "File exist here. 

   cd %%F

 Echo %%F | FINDSTR /C:"node" >Installing node packages" nul & IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (

Echo Installing node packages"

npm install

.\node_modules\.bin\karma start --reporters html

) else (ECHO CASE FALSE)

) ELSE (
   ECHO "File not exist") 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Running all solution at once Angular CLI and Karma CLI**

```
$testProjects = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:WORKSPACE -Filter "karma.conf.js" -Recurse | ForEach-Object FullName | Select-String -notmatch "node_modules"

foreach ($project in $testProjects)
{
$project = $project -replace "karma.conf.js",""


Set-Location -Path $project
npm install


if(Test-Path $project".angular-cli.json")
{
Write-Host "***** angular cli project *****"
Write-Host "File path : "$project
.\node_modules\.bin\ng test -code-coverage

}
else{
Write-Host "***** karma cli project *****"
.\node_modules\.bin\karma start --reporters html

$reportName = "report.html"

$leafName = Split-Path $project -leaf
$newReportName = $leafName + ".html"
Rename-Item $reportName $newReportName

Copy-Item -Path $newReportName -Destination C:\

Remove-Item $newReportName
}

}
```